# How to replace a for loop on the graph creation

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I created a tensorflow graph with some recurrent pattern in order to implement a Reinforcement Learning.
In order to generate agent results, I need to compute 140 times the sames matmul and use all intermediate results.

It's why, i'm using a for loop with list objects to do this.
The graph look like this :

[image: graph render]

but this solution consume a lot of resources.
Someone can lead me to a prettier way to implement my algorithm. 
Thank's !

Comment: You need to show us what you have so far, preferably a minimal example that illustrates the problem, and better define what it is you want.

Comment: For instance : 

agent_input = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[nb_agent,10])] <br/>
agent_order = list() <br/>
for i in range(nb_iteration): <br/>
         agent_order.append(multilayer_perceptron(agent_input[-1], weights, biases)) <br/>
        agent_input.append(multilayer_perceptron_bis(agent_order[-1], weights, biases)) <br/>